# privilege comes with responsibility

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

This CNN article titled "[With UN vote, Trump gets what he deserves](https://edition.cnn.com/2017/12/21/opinions/haley-un-vote-what-trump-deserves-john-kirby-opinion/index.html)" has this passage:

> There was nothing principled or realistic about what Trump and UN
>   Ambassador Nikki Haley tried to do this week. But then, I think they
>   knew they were asking for it. They knew the scrutiny they were going
>   to receive. And I think they like playing the victim. I think they
>   believe victimhood lends credence to their anger and sense of
>   entitlement. It makes it easier for them to play to a base of voters
>   who believe international cooperation and compromise are weaknesses.
>
> "When a nation is singled out for attack in this organization," said
>   Haley in her speech to the UN on Thursday, "that nation is
>   disrespected. What's more, that nation is asked to pay for the
>   privilege of being disrespected. In the case of the US, we are asked
>   to pay more than anyone else for that dubious privilege."
>
> Haley should remember that **privilege comes with responsibility**, that
>   respect must be earned -- even nurtured -- and that the United Nations
>   isn't one of Trump's country clubs. It's a deliberative body of
>   sovereign states who have just as much right to express their will as
>   we do. Compromise and accommodation come with the territory.

In the first sentence of the last paragraph, there's this clause:

> **privilege comes with responsibility**

This clause acts as a subordinate clause in the sentence.

Normally, I'm familiar with the adage "With privilege comes responsibility". 
In the context of the above article, is "privilege comes with responsibility" used to mean "with privilege comes responsibility"?

If so, are the two generally interchangeable?

Comment: I deleted my answer. The definition didn't fit with what I said.

Comment: "With privilege comes responsibility," is an idiom, as you already noted. "Privilege comes with responsibility" is what the author states in the article, not using the idiom. Although the literal meaning is different, the implication is the same. *With* is a bidirectional. "She went with him" and "He went with her" are literally different but effectively mean the same thing.

Comment: @Kris not in this case. According to [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-with) one is the result of the other.

Comment: @Kris the first definition. In this context, the writer wants to say that one impliez the existence of the other. So the literal meaning and the implication are different.